# echo post wont post string after space

Tags: php

I made a code to post data in a table describing a product  but it only gets the word before the space, when I use `print_r` it gives the complete string.

Can someone help?

```
<?php

for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['codProduto']); $i++){ ?>

    <tr>              
        <td><input type="text" name="descProduto[]" id="descProduto"   value=<?php echo $_POST['descProduto'][$i]?>  readonly></td>
    </tr>

<?php }?>
```

this code  gives complete strings:

```
<?php 
print_r( $_POST['descProduto'] );
?>
```

like this:

```
Array ( [0] => CONJUNTO TOMADA 2P+T 10A 250V PL/BR [1] => CONJUNTO TOMADA 2P+T 20A 250V PL/BR [2] => MODULO TOMADA 2P+T 10A 250V 1M BR )
```

but the first code only get `CONJUNTO` and `MODULO` in each cell.

Comment: You need to quote your value on your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you forgot the quotes.  If this emits two words:

```
value=<?php echo $_POST['descProduto'][$i]?>
```

it would render as this:

```
value=Two Words
```

So your HTML element has an attribute called `value` with a value of `Two`, and a *separate* attribute called `Words` with no value.

HTML attributes are supposed to be enclosed in quotes:

```
value="<?php echo $_POST['descProduto'][$i]?>"
```

Comment: **And** escaped with `htmlentities` in case of a quote.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have quotes around your attributes.

```
value="<?php echo $_POST['descProduto'][$i]?>"
```